# Why is This If statement not recognising the 'Then'?

Tags: vb.net, if-statement

Why is this `If` Statement not recognising the `Then`'s and is just saying "Expression Expected" with a blue underline under the two last `Then`'s, the first one is fine.

```
If fst <> "" And lst = "" Then
    cmd = New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE FirstName='" & fst & "';", cn)
ElseIf fst = "" And lst = <> Then
    cmd = New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE Surname='" & lst & "';", cn)
ElseIf fst <> "" And lst = <> Then
    cmd = New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE Surname='" & lst & "' AND FirstName='" & fst & "';", cn)
End If
```

Comment: What the heck does `lst = <>` mean?!

Comment: Also please see [How do I create a parameterized SQL query? Why Should I?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/542510/11683)

Answer (score 0):

```
If fst <> "" And lst = "" Then
    ' statement...
ElseIf fst = "" And lst = "" Then
    ' statement...
ElseIf fst <> "" And lst = "" Then
    ' statement...
End If
```